# System diagram that users can drill down into

Tags: microsoft-visio, documentation, diagrams

I am soon going to be creating some system architecture at work.

Like any large system, there are different levels from which you can view the system. Very high, down to the nitty gritty.

I was wondering if there are any tools out there that allow you to create a single document (probably in html) whereby you can start the document with a high-level overview, and then drill down into sections or connections to give you a more detailed view, and then in turn, drill down into those sections in turn and then come back up at will.

I guess what I'm looking for is a simple visio clone for system diagrams, where clicking on the node or connection in a file takes you to a another visio file which is a more detailed view of what you clicked.

I have looked through the questions on SU, and haven't seen anything that can do what I ask without writing up the documentation myself in HTML. Please don't mark this as a duplicate off-the-cuff, though of course I'll gladly look at any suggested duplicates to see if they can do what I ask.

Many thanks.